# Is L2 Cache Miss equivalent to "L2 Data Cache Refill" on ARMv7 A15?

Tags: arm, performancecounter

I am trying to determine which hardware counters available on the ARM Cortex A15 processor are the correct ones to use for determining system-wide L2 cache misses.

My application here is a kernel-level voltage-frequency governor (i.e. it could substitute for the ondemand governor). Because I need access to performance counters at the system level and not attached to a particular program runtime, I am not using existing utilities such as PAPI or Linux's perf tool. From my past experiences with both I understand that these are better used to monitor the performance stats for a particular program or instrumented binary.

I have implemented a kernel module that periodically updates several hardware counter values to sysfs endpoints. The resources I have used include:

- [Performance Counter Sampling on the Exynos 5422](https://pietrotech.wordpress.com/)
- [Arm Technical Reference Manual (Specifically Ch. 11 on the Performance Monitoring Unit)](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0388e/BEHEDIHI.html)
- Searches in perf and PAPI code & documentation to see if L2 misses is a derived counter rather than a native one.

The hardware counter I am currently using to measure L2 misses is event 0x17: "L2 data cache refill". Printing this value consistently gives 0, even when running data-heavy benchmarks. Is there a different event or set of events I should be using to determine L2 cache misses? Perhaps 0x13, "Data memory accesses", or some composite of events?

It is very possible that the root of my question is a misunderstanding of "L2 data cache refills", but I have not been able to find a clarification on this through documentation and stack overflow searches.

**EDIT**: I have found that L2 refills was reading 0 because the 5th hardware counter for some reason is not working as expected; re-assigning L2 refills to a different counter has resolved this particular issue.

**EDIT 2:** That 5th hardware counter was not function because I had not enabled that many. Silly me.

Comment: My question of if cache refills necessarily means the same as cache misses still stands. My thought on this is yes, because externally triggered cache events (such as coherence evictions) would not count as refills, but as evictions.

Comment: Thinking of this further, cache refills may be counted when the prefetching unit brings a cache line in before it is accessed. This wouldn't be a cache miss (and hopefully prevents one, in fact). So refills would be a superset of misses?

Answer (score 2):

Quote from a different [ARM manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100403/0200/debug-descriptions/performance-monitor-unit/pmu-events?lang=en) implies refills are not just misses:

L1 data cache refill:
"This event counts all allocations into the L1 cache. This includes read linefills, store linefills, and prefetch linefills."